# How efficient is faceting on timestamp attributes in Algolia?

Tags: algolia

Let's say you have events in an Algolia index.
These events have several timestamp attributes (`startAt`, `endAt`, `createdAt`...).

If you configure these attributes to be a facet, is there an impact on Algolia indexation performance?

It sound natural to say "yes", because there is an infinite set of values in such attributes.
But I would like to know of there is any kind of documentation about the "nature" of attributes that should/shouldn't be facet?

Comment: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/sending-and-managing-data/prepare-your-data/in-depth/prepare-data-in-depth/#filters-and-facets

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that already, but not helping, only thing it says is "add attributes based on what your end users want to fine-tune their search". So it might also be timestamp

Comment: i think you may have to post this on algolia discourse as well. you can get an answer from staff members there

Comment: Good idea, just did, will post here the answer if answered, thanks.

Comment: My first post was Akismeted, had to repost, still have no answer https://discourse.algolia.com/t/indexation-performance-for-timestamp-attributes-with-facet/15936